# Solving problems that DTM can't solve

Tags: computability, undecidability

Let L be a problem that DTM can't solve. Can we prove that there is an abstract machine that can solve this problem?

Here, L is not Halting problem or Hilbert's tenth problem (because we proved that algorithms for these don't exist).

In other words, is there an abstract machine more powerful than DTM? If not, how do we prove it?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your question. I can't work out what you mean by "because we prove this problems cant solve yet". I think that the answer might just be that there are abstract machines that can solve any problem: you can just _define_ a machine that accepts if its input is in $L$ and reject if it isn't.

Comment: You say "I think that the answer might just be that there are abstract machines that can solve any problem" Then we can define an abstract machine that can solve halting problem , if we can do this , then why we say that this problem is undisable

Comment: *By definition*, an algorithm is whatever can be implemented by a Turing machine.

Comment: So there are no algorithms that the Turing machine can not do.
Please put that comment in the form of an answer to select it and close the question @YuvalFilmus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We define computable functions to be those computable by a (deterministic) Turing machine, and we identify algorithms with computable functions. Therefore, *by fiat*, any algorithm can be implemented on a Turing machine.

Whether this is the correct definition of the intuitive concept of algorithm is the subject of the [Church–Turing thesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing_thesis). The fact that many models of computation are known to be equivalent strengthens the thesis, but since it's not a mathematical statement, it is impossible to prove.

Comment: Therefore,By definition, there is no stronger machine than Turing, and this is equivalent to the Thesis(Alan-Church) But it is possible that the thesis is wrong
Because we really can not prove the thesis because it is not a mathematical statement